# How to update field in a table based on existence of a row in a query in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, join

I have an MS Access table with one field I want to update based upon whether a key exists in a separate query.  I have tried to research and found similar but not the same problems (e.g. [Access 2003 - Running an update query based on select query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424110/access-2003-running-an-update-query-based-on-select-query-results)), but I can't work out how to convert them to my situation.

Basically I have made a query that returns the primary key for all the entries that need updating.

So

Query: "temp" returns KeywordID for all records I want to change.  It is 24K records

Then I have the table I want to update

Table: "keywords" has a field "priority" and I want to set this to Yes for every record where the KeywordID is in the temp query. There are about 900K rows.

I can't work out what I'm supposed to do: Here are all the wrong ways I've tried:

```
UPDATE keywords SET keywords.Priority = Yes  JOIN temp ON keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID ; ' SYNTAX error

UPDATE keywords SET keywords.Priority = Yes INNER JOIN temp ON keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID ; ' SYNTAX error

UPDATE keywords INNER JOIN temp ON keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID SET keywords.Priority = Yes; ' Must use an updatable query

UPDATE keywords SET keywords.Priority = Yes WHERE EXISTS (SELECT temp.KeywordID from TEMP); ' tries to update 900K records
```

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Currently don't have access to test this but this should be worth a try</strike>

UPDATE keywords SET keywords.Priority = Yes JOIN temp on keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID WHERE keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID;

UPDATE keywords INNER JOIN temp ON keywords.ID = temp.ID SET keywords.Priority = True;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @a-shareef but that gives me "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'yes JOIN temp on keywords.KeywordID = temp.KeywordID'."

Comment: Just realized you tried this already.  Is keywords a query or a table?

Comment: keywords is a table.  temp is a query, very complex which is based in part on keywords

Comment: So this query will work if you create a table called temp (instead of select query, convert into make table).  I think since temp is directly related to keywords it can't update.

Comment: Ok that solves it. Thanks. So really the problem here is on trying to use a query based on the table I'm trying to change. Using a temp table fixes it, but is an unfortunate two-step process.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This example may not require you to make a temp table first:

```
UPDATE keywords
SET Priority = -1
WHERE keywordID IN (SELECT keywordID FROM temp)
```

If Priority is a Yes/No field, then -1 has the same effect as True